# Should we change the name of the chatroom? If so, to what?

Tags: discussion

People in the chat itself have [suggested changing the name](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17096872#17096872). It seems "Game Development" is too uninteresting. Propose names here, and we'll change the name to the most upvoted answer in a week or so.

Downvotes mean "I don't like this name" and upvotes mean "I like this name."

Comment: A link to the relevant chat discussion might help people make decisions about this.

Comment: Added. sdhsdhdjjmed

Comment: The overwhelming consensus here appears to be that we should not change the name. Thus, we will not.

Answer (score 14):

The current name is fine, no need to change it.

Comment: I don't see a huge reason to change the name at all. Especially to something "clever" like the things Blue points out in his similar answer about silly and opaque chat names.

Comment: Considering the entire "change the name discussion" was a single offhand comment. I don't think the name needs to be changed at all.

Comment: am i the only one who finds it weird the site is titled "Game Development" and the chat is self-titled "Game Development" as well.  just seems weird to me

Comment: @Joe You are the only one.

Comment: @Joe I think it's weird too

Answer (score 5):

When I look through the chat rooms listings I see:

`The Pod Bay`

`The Loop`

`The Bridge`

`The Garden Shed`

And you know what, I have no idea what SE site those are relevant to without needing to read the description. I think the name as it is right now is perfect. Easy for new people to locate, easy to see at a glance and fits in the side bar without stretching it.

Comment: A vote for this answer is a vote for [the no change needed](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/1707/7191) answer.

Comment: Does that mean we effectively get to vote twice? ;)

Answer (score -2):

Once upon a time, this room was called "Gamedev Down Hall" or "Town hall" or "Down Town" or something like that. I never understood why was it changed, since I liked that name better.

It doesn't have the problem @Blue mentioned, while it's not as boring as exact same name of channel.

Comment: After some talks and some searchs, it seems it's all my imagination. We never had that name, but then again it doesn't mean we shouldn't.

Answer (score -5):

### Default Player

The default player is designed by the development team to fit the majority of users (or all users when there is no editing system).  Also maintains that this is *game* development, not just any programming.

Answer (score -5):

`Chat<GameDev>`

It fits better with the Game Development theme than `Chat<Gamedev>`.